# Compile PHP with libjpeg-6b

Tags: php, legacy, libjpeg

for legacy-reasons I'd like to have a PHP-binary compiled against the ancient libjpeg-6b ("v62") lib. According to [PHP-manual](https://www.php.net/manual/de/image.installation.php) this is still supported. Hence, I downloaded the desired PHP-source (5.7 in my case) and tried to compile:

```
./configure --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir="/path/libjpeg" && make
```

This works just fine, however the compiled binary still uses the global version which is v80. I'm compiling on a fully updated ArchLinux (5.14.7-arch1-1)

```
% ldd ./custom_php
[...]
libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f83c14bf000)
```

Also, `--enable-static` plus `--disable-shared` didn't work! So: How can I compile a PHP-binary that the desired version of libjpeg?